# Where can I find build system option in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm building a VR application in unity version 2019.1.2f1 but I can't seem to find the "build system" option in build settings, has it been removed?

I've when into build settings and searched "build system" but still nothing.

**Here is my unity screenshot.**
[image: Myscreen]

**What I'm looking for screenshot.**
[image: Build systems option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal build system is not in the latest version of Unity. The internal build system has been removed [since 2019.1.0b1](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/2019.1.0b1).

> Android: Remove internal build system

Unity now only supports the Gradle build system for Android.